# TheFuzz Library in Python - Ratio Function

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to understand how the ratio is calculated in this function. I've been searching all over the internet and even asking ChatGPT about it, but I can't find a single answer.

The issue is that, for example:

```
from thefuzz import fuzz #fuzzywuzzy library is the same

a = 'house'
b = 'mouse'

print(fuzz.ratio(a, b))`
```

This returns 80, which can be achieved by (max(len(a,b)) - LevDist)/ max(len(a,b))
However, if we were to change b = 'mousee', the ratio returns 73 and the formula no longer works.

I've also tried other formulas such as the one explained in this [DataCamp Article](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/fuzzy-string-python), but it's not consistent with this case and other.

Can someone help me understand how the ratio is calculated? Thanks

Comment: You can look at the source.  https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz/blob/master/thefuzz/fuzz.py  It's not `max(len(a,b))`, it's `len(a)+len(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzywuzzy uses `python-Levenshtein` if available and otherwise falls back to `difflib`. They usw different algorithms to determine a string similarity:

1. if `python-Levenshtein` is available `Levenshtein.ratio` is used. This calculates a normalized Version of the InDel distance (similar to Levenshtein distance, but does not allow substitutions). The normalization is performed as: `100 * (1 - (InDel_dist / (len(a)+len(b))))`
2. if it isn't available it uses [`difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio)